# Finding and configuring existing nginx installation on CentOS7

Tags: nginx, centos, nginx-location

I have Wordpress installed on a CentOS 7 machine. When I try to upload a 17MB theme, I get an error saying:

```
"413 Request Entity Too Large
      nginx/1.8.1"
```

I searched online and I configured php.ini post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 32M, but I still get that error.
I searched further, and there is a configuration on nginx.conf where you state:

```
"client_max_body_size 0;"
```

Now comes the strange part. I can't find nginx.conf file.
I have searched for /nginx folder on /etc, but it is nowhere to be found.
I run a command "whereis nginx", and this come up:

```
"/usr/lib64/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man3/nginx.3pm.gz /usr/share/man/man8/nginx.8.gz"
```

But none of these places I can find the nginx.conf file.
If I run the command "sudo service nginx restart", the output is "nginx: unrecognized service".
It looks like it is not installed, but I still get that 413 error by nginx 1.81.
I don't know how to uninstall the current version 1.81, because I can't find it.
What should I do to find nginx installation and configure it?